# How to save the output of a loop that increases by a sequence

Tags: r, loops, for-loop

So i'm trying to save the output of a loop that is going 5 by 5 instead of 1 by 1. 
The code i have is:

```
for ( i in seq(40,200,by=5)){
  test=StatArb(Col,Bog,i,100,1.1)
  print(test[2])
}
```

I created the `function StatArb` and the output is a list of 6 elements. I want the second one which is a single number. Instead of printing the result I want it to store it in a vector. I have tried creating a vector and replacing each i entry by the result of the test, but it doesn't work. The code is:

```
vector = rep(0,32)
for ( i in seq(40,200,by=5)){
      test=StatArb(Col,Bog,i,100,1.1)
      vector[i] = test[i]
    }
```

But for some reason in the loop it expands the vector from 32 to 200 and so I get a lot of Null numbers.

Comment: Use a counter `k` in the body of the loop that you iterate (`k <- k + 1`), and use that to index the vector.

Comment: @bouncyball thanks for the answer but i don't understand, can you elaborate a little bit more. you mean like before the test put `k = k+1` and then `vector[k] = test[2]`. I don't think this is it, doesn't look right

Comment: I think looking at what the result of `seq(40, 200 by = 5)` should give you a good hint to where you're going wrong. Your condition in the for loop should probably be for `i in 1:32`. Right now you're passing 40, 45, 50, ... 200, as `i`. It doesn't look like it's what you want. For example, `vector[45]`  ie, position 45 when your vector is of length 32 filled with 0.

Comment: @BrandonBertelsen i know it is what i want because the i I'm replacing is a window size and i don't want it to be 1 to 32 y want it to be 40, 45,.... I don't wan't to loop 160 times just 32 to see how my results change.

Comment: Yes, but in R, when you have a vector, it expands to the size of the new position. `x <- 1`, `x[100] <- 1` Now look at `x`, it's filled with 99 NA values. Try my suggestion, `i in 1:32` then in your function, use a basic formula `i*5 + 35` to pass 40 through 200.

Comment: @BrandonBertelsen thanks i didn't understand it the first time it works perfectly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

```
sapply(seq(40,200,5), function(i) { StatArb(Col,Bog,i,100,1.1)[2]})
```